# Change value in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

My company name is changing. So I need to change value from IIS.com to IIP.com in mysql database. Where it has IIS.com, I need to change IIP.com

Comment: I can use update statement. but I think it has in many tables. So I dont know whats the best way. Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: It really depends on where this data is stored, how it's encoded, and what collisions that might have with other data. The hack solution is to dump with `mysqldump`, do a string replace, and restore. The more elegant solution is to tackle each column and table individually with a custom strategy. If you have "iis.com" as well as things like "xyziis.com" in your database you'll need to be very careful when doing substitutions.